# Difference between patch and diff files

Tags: linux, svn, git

Could somebody explain me the difference between a **.diff** file and **.patch** file.

Comment: Actually patch is a utility to apply diffs. Extension doesn't matter.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

What matters is the content of the file, not the extension. Both of those extensions imply that some sort of diff utility (`diff`, `git diff`, `git format-patch`, `svn diff`) produced the output.

Many diff utilities produce output which can be applied by the `patch` command. You will frequently need to use the `-d` and `-p` options to `patch` in order to get the paths matched up right (strip prefix, name target directory). If you see one of those extensions on a file distributed online, it's almost certainly an indication it's compatible with `patch`.

Git's diff output is compatible with patch, but I believe svn's is not. Of course, plain patches generated by `git diff` are probably best applied by `git apply`, and patches generated by `git format-patch` are designed for use with `git-am`.

Answer (score 10):

patch is a unified diff (-u), if you do a:
`diff -u oldfile newfile`,
with patch command line,  you can apply the differences to oldfile to become newfile somewhere else.

Comment: I like this idea. Patches being a collection of diffs.  I wasn't looking for a "correct extension" but a maybe a standard practice for naming.  Whether or not this is in common use, it makes sense to me. I'll go forward using .diff for single file diffs and .patch for multiple consolidated diffs.

Answer (score 6):

There are no differences. `diff` utility produces a patch file which is applied using `patch`.

Comment: That is to say, when you use `diff` to create the patch, you call it foo.diff or foo.patch (or anything else).  The `patch` program doesn't care.

Comment: so if a diff file is given and it is said that you should use it for patching the source, what does it imply. Can i use the patch -d <name of the directory which contains source to be patched> -p[n] <name of the diff file> command to patch it?

Comment: @Sen: "Can I use `patch`...?" The best answer there is "try it and see". If the patch doesn't apply, or `patch` can't read it, you'll get errors. If it works, it works.

Comment: `-d ... -p` are to avoid creating the same directory structure as where the patch has been generated. e.g. if the patch file contains `/home/user/projects/p1/prog.c` and needs to be applied to `/home/anotheruser/work/project1/prog.c`, `patch -d /home/anotheruser/work/project <file.patch` does it. But if there are two files to be patched - `prog.c lib/lib.c`, you need to do `patch -d /home/anotheruser/work/project1 -p5 <file.patch`

Answer (score 5):

For me `.diff` files contain file differences only (added/deleted lines) that are produced by "git diff"

`.patch` files for me also contain the author, date and patch/commit message, as generated by `git show`.

---

Github allows to add `.patch` and `.diff` to pull request URLs.
The `.diff` contains only the file changes, while the `.patch` is a serialization of all commits in that PR, with the commit message and file content diff in each.