# Git patch from several (not all) unstaged files

Tags: git, version-control, diff, git-diff, git-patch

I read about `git patch` command, but all of the examples show how to get a patch for all not staged or cached files or even all files that some commit includes (from one commit till another). But suppose I have **10 not staged files** and I need to create **one proper patch** just **for 6** of them. How can I do this? And if there is a way to create such patch, how can I apply it?
Sorry if obvious.

Comment: Do you mean `git format-patch`?

Comment: `git diff -- file1 ... file6` will produce an output which can be fed to `git apply`

Comment: @Adam I mean some patch, which I want to apply for the same directory without any errors.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to define the phrase *proper patch* first.  What makes a patch proper?  What makes one improper?  For that matter, what's the difference between a *patch* and a *diff?*  There is no one fixed answer, but see [Difference between patch and diff files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4215722/1256452).

That said, `git diff` produces diffs, and is quite flexible.  It's meant for human use, not for use by machines, so its output may or may not be what you want (especially since you did not define any of your terms).  The `git format-patch` program is less flexible and meant more for use by machines: it produces output that can be digested easily by `git apply`, which is meant to apply a single patch without committing it, or `git am`, which is meant to apply a whole series of patches stored on your computer in "mailbox format", committing each one.  (`am` here is short for Apply Mailbox, more or less.)

Because you haven't defined your terms, there's no single right answer to your question.  If we assume you mean *produce a file that `git apply` can apply*, we get one possible answer.  If we assume you mean *produce a mailbox-format patch that `git am` can apply and commit*, we get a different answer.

The `git format-patch` command will produce a mailbox formatted patch (or series of patches) from some *commit or commits*.  So to use it, you *must make a commit*.  You can simply commit those particular files you wish to have in your patch, on a new branch if you like.  (See the long details below.)

The `git diff` program, or any of its more machine-oriented related commands (`git diff-tree`, `git diff-files`, `git diff-index`) will produce a human-readable diff.  If it is not colorized, it will be suitable for use with `git apply`.  To use these, you need not make a commit.

As [LeGEC noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63340447/git-patch-from-several-not-all-unstaged-files#comment112003571_63340447), you can use `git diff` on specific files.  Note that by default, `git diff -- paths` compare the *index copy* of each specified path to the *work-tree copy* of the same path.  This is probably what you want.  If you have configured `git diff` to always produce colorized output, turn that off for the duration of the one `git diff` operation.  Save the output somewhere:

```
git diff -- file1 ... fileN > /tmp/patch
```

or:

```
git diff --color=never -- file1 ... fileN > /tmp/patch
```

if you need to disable colorization.

## Long: about commits

**If the above suffices, there's no need to read the rest of this.**

If your definition of *proper patch* means one that `git am` can turn into a *commit*, you will need to make a new commit.  This is where knowing what *staged* vs *not staged*, and how branch names and commits all work, becomes very important.

Git is really, at its heart, all about commits.  Branches—or more specifically, branch *names*—are useful, especially if you are a human, but they're not really what Git is about.  Git is all about the *commits*.

Every commit is numbered, but the numbers are not simple sequential counts.  We can't find commit #1, then commit #2, and so on.  Instead, each commit gets a unique *hash ID*.  This thing *looks* random, but in fact is entirely non-random, and is carefully computed so that *every* Git will number a 100%-identical, bit-for-bit-the-same commit the same way.  That way, every Git everywhere will agree that *this* commit gets *this* hash ID, and no other commit gets this hash ID.

What goes into a commit comes in two parts: the *data*, and the *metadata:*

- The data in a commit is pretty simple: it's a full snapshot of *every file that Git knows about*.

  This obviously makes Git repositories grow enormously fat, since every commit stores every file.  But they don't (grow enormously fat).  The reason is that the files are stored in a special, read-only, Git-only, compressed and de-duplicated format.  If you make a thousand commits, each with 1000 files, but *re-use* 999 of the 1000 files each time, then all thousand commits *share* 999 files with other commits.

  (There is more to it than this, but the de-duplication is the first step, and a very big one.)
- The *metadata* in a commit is information about the commit.  This is where Git stores the name and email address of the person who made the commit, for instance.  In this metadata, Git stores one particular set of information that Git needs for itself, though.  Every commit stores the *commit number*—the hash ID—of its *parent* commit.  This is how history exists in a repository.

Since the files in the commits are *read-only*—and Git-only, frozen-for-all-time, compressed into this special freeze-dried format that only Git itself can use—the files *you work with* have to be *extracted* from commits.  This is what `git checkout` (or, since Git 2.23, `git switch`) does.  You pick a commit and tell Git: *Extract all the files from this commit, so that I can see them and work with / on them.*

Since each commit remembers its *previous* commit, all you need to do, to *use* Git, is have Git remember for you the unique hash ID of the *last* commit.  This is where branch names come in.  **A branch name simply holds the hash ID of the *last* commit that is to be treated as part of that branch.**

This means we can draw a branch like this:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <--master
```

The *name* `master` holds the actual hash ID of the *last* commit, which at this point is hash ID `H`.  That commit holds a snapshot of all of your files, and also holds the hash ID of earlier commit `G`.

Git can look up any commit—any internal object, really—by its hash ID, so Git can look up commit `H`, extract all of its files, and let you work on it.  Or, Git can look up commit `H`, find its parent hash ID `G`, and look up commit `G`.  Git can then extract `G`'s files, or look up its parent hash ID `F`.  This is the first of the big secrets of Git.

#### Commits, your work-tree, and the index

Given the above—read-only commits, and read/write files—we have already seen that Git must *extract* a commit into an area where you can see and work on your files.  This area is your *working tree* or *work-tree*.  So there are two copies of each file of interest: the one in the current commit, which is frozen for all time, and the one in your work-tree, which you can use.  It's pretty straightforward, with one twist: you can create files in this area that Git *doesn't* know about.

The really tricky part here, though, is how Git makes a *new commit*, and what files Git *does* know about.  You might think that Git would just keep a list of file names, for instance, and use your work-tree files to make new commits ... but it doesn't.

Instead, Git keeps a *third* copy—well, a *de-duplicated* copy, in the freeze-dried format—in an in-between place.  Between the current commit and your work-tree, Git has this *other* "copy" (already de-duplicated, so not exactly a copy) of *each file that Git took out of the commit at checkout time*.

These in-between "copies" of each file are in what Git calls, variously, the *index*, or the *staging area*, or (rarely these days) the *cache*.  Note that these copies are ready to go into a new commit, as they're already in the Git-only, freeze-dried format.  Unlike the copies in the commits themselves, they *can* be replaced, though.

This is what `git add` is all about.  The `git add` command means *Make the index copy of some file(s) match the work-tree copy.*  If you have changed a file in your work-tree, you must tell Git to copy the updated file back into Git's index.

This is what a *staged file* is.  At all times, Git's index has copies of each file that Git knows about.  If it's in the index, it's ready to be committed—but maybe it's *the same* as the file in the current commit!  If so, it's already de-duplicated, and Git can easily tell that it's the same.

If the index copy of a file is *different* from the current commit copy, or is entirely new, then what will go into the next commit is *different* from what is in the current commit.  Git calls that *staged*.  If the index copy is *the same* as the committed copy, though, Git says nothing at all.

Meanwhile, the index copy of a file might match the work-tree copy, or not.  If the index copy *does* match the work-tree file, Git doesn't say anything about it.  If not, Git says that the file is *unstaged*.

This means a file can be both *staged for commit* and *not staged for commit*, at the same time!  If the committed copy (which can't be changed) doesn't match the index copy, *and* the index copy doesn't match the work-tree copy, you have a file that is both *staged for commit* and *not staged for commit*.  You can get this state by doing:

```
git checkout somebranch
edit file.ext             # change something in a file
git add file.ext          # copy the updated file back into Git's index
edit file.ext             # change something else in the same file
```

When you run `git commit`, what Git does is to make a new commit from whatever is in Git's index at that time.  So if you have ten unstaged files right now, and you `git add` six of them and then run `git commit`, you get a new commit in which:

- six files don't match the previous commit (the one that's current *before* you run `git commit`), but
- all the other files *do* match the previous commit.

Now that you have made the new commit, the new commit is the current commit.  You made it *from* the files that are in the index, so all files in the new, now-current commit *match* all the files that are in the index.  No files are "staged for commit", but the four files you *didn't* `git add` are still there in your work-tree, still different from the corresponding four files in the index and those four files in the current commit.  So these four files are still "not staged for commit".

If you like, you can now `git add` these four files to copy the work-tree versions back into Git's index, and then `git commit` the result.  You now have *two* new commits that you did not have before.  The last one matches your work-tree, so that the current commit, Git's index, and your work-tree all match: no files are staged and no files are unstaged.

#### More about branch names

Note that each time you do make a new commit, Git has to update the *current branch name*.  Suppose you're on your `master` branch initially, like this:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
```

Now you create a *new* branch name, such as `feature`.  This new name *also* identifies commit `H`.  We'll add the name `HEAD`, in all capital letters, to one of the branch names to show which one we're using:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- feature (HEAD), master
```

Now we'll `git add` some file(s) and make a new commit.  It will get a new random-looking hash ID; we'll just call this `I`:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I
```

The trick is that Git now writes `I`'s hash ID into the *name* `feature`—the one `HEAD` is attached-to—so that the name points to `I` now:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

If we add some more files and `git commit` again, we get another new commit `J`:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I--J   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

Note that each commit has a full snapshot of *every* file, as it appeared in Git's index at the time you ran `git commit`.  When you use `git format-patch` to turn a commit into a patch, Git:

- extracts the files from commit's *parent* (e.g., `H` for `I`);
- extracts the files from the commit (`I`);
- compares the extracted files; and
- tells you which files are *different*, giving you a recipe for changing the older versions into the newer ones.

Since this is a commit-able patch, Git adds a header to it giving the name and email address of the person who made the commit, an appropriate date-and-time stamp, and the log message in which whoever made the commit explains *why* they made that commit.  The patch itself comes after this header.